# Ajax bugs with internet explorer cached

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer

Recently working on my company i'm realize that start to having troubles with some methods which return html based on partial views. The problem was specifically that the changes was not loaded by internet explorer because this browsers has some configures to remains in cache the information and then you cannot see the changes base on the partial view. This changes was not affected in other browsers like firefox and chrome.

The problem was solved modifying the options of internet explorer and checking this options on the browsers client

[image]

So. I have a couple of questions

1. Is there some configuration or meta tag that i can used in javascript, html or jquery to handle this kind of error without modified the browser configuration.
2. Where i can find some documentation about this troubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If issue is only ajax related...try setting `cache:false` in your ajax options. If using convenience methods like get() or load() can do this globally using $.ajaxSetup()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Answer (score 1):

Serve your HTML content with suitable `Cache-Control`/`Expires` headers to get the caching strategy you want. The user settings are there for content that doesn't specify any particular strategy.

Or you could of course add a `?randomtoken` cachebreaker in the loading script for the quick client-side fix.

Answer (score 1):

Might be that's not a bug it is a feature :) (just kidding).
Try changing you're link every time you refresh you're page (partial view...). Just add something new to the end of link. Something like random number or second in the day...

```
1. request: http://www.test.com?nocache=12669
2. request: http://www.test.com?nocache=12789
...
```